# Odoo 10 how to get the actual purchase_price (cost) of product in sales orders

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

When a sales order is generated, there is a field purchase_price to reflect the cost of the product in each sales order line.

There is a field for that cost in product definition.

However, in many situations cost depends on the quantity of product that you order to your supplier, hence a fixed single cost per product is not accurate/feasible for many scenarios.

Is it possible to make Odoo use average cost based on historical purchase records? Is there any other alternative to get more meaningful cost / purchase_price values in sales orders?

Odoo 10

Thanks,

Comment: Hi there, you can use pricelists for this purpose

Comment: could you please elaborate? I have tried to use pricelist to display purchase price in sales order, without success.

Comment: Pricelists has difficult structure, it allows you to make discounts set custom price for specific client and event allows you to set formula how to calculate prices so its just not that easy to just tell you in comments.

Comment: Question is related to purchase_price (cost), not to sale prices. I think you refer to sale pricelists which would not allow to implement a solution for this issue